# Exception when calling sheet.insertChart() in a GAS script: Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Receiving the following exception when calling `insertChart` in a GAS script:
I get the following error when calling `sheet.insertChart()` function:

> Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id 1YeMWSkmX7RN2DkLAQQiE0jEUxyNzP3q60aDA0mhYmhk.

Like many of the other issues that have reported this exception this script had been working fine for years. This issue came out of the blue and has rendered the sheet unusable. The code where the error is being thrown is very straightforward. It is simply looping through an array of charts and inserting them into the sheet:

```js
  for(i = 0; i < charts.length; i++){
    console.time("populateExhibitFrames(): Insert and Update Chart");    
    dbSheet.insertChart(charts[i]);
    console.timeEnd("populateExhibitFrames(): Insert and Update Chart");    
  }
```

The sheet does not contain a huge amount of data

[minimum reproducible example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YeMWSkmX7RN2DkLAQQiE0jEUxyNzP3q60aDA0mhYmhk/edit?pli=1#gid=504792217)

To reproduce the error, from the custom menu item select LAD Options/Build Dashboards/Build Simple Dashboard

The error is thrown on line 863 of the Dashboards/DashboardBuilder.gs file

Comment: I don't see any accesses to document by id in your example.  So I can even guess an answer.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] including the textual error message (the file name and line number are missing)

Comment: Here is the [minimal reproducible example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YeMWSkmX7RN2DkLAQQiE0jEUxyNzP3q60aDA0mhYmhk/edit?pli=1#gid=2131577807) that reproduces the error. To produce the error from the custom menu item select LAD Options/Build Dashboards/Build Simple Dashboard. The error is as follows: Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id 1YeMWSkmX7RN2DkLAQQiE0jEUxyNzP3q60aDA0mhYmhk. The error occurs on line 863 of the Dashboards/DashboardsBuilder.gs file

Comment: @Boomer nit: the logs say it's at line 797. If this rather large system has been working for a while unchanged, I suspect that some upstream data is making its way in unsanitized. Perhaps try logging what's in the chart right before you insert it, and see if anything looks out of place in the last attempt (the one that fails)

Comment: It turns out this is a [known bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/182701055)

Comment: Hi Boomer - Yes I just wanted to confirm that it is a Bug... My 2000 users have started seeing the issue, and it seems to be more and more frequent